# Merging List with same index?

Tags: c#, list

Example: if I have list 1, 2, 3 like this:

```
var list1 = new List<string> {"B", "S", "", "", "", "", ""};
var list2 = new List<string> {"", "", "B", "S", "", "", ""};
var list3 = new List<string> {"", "", "", "", "B", "S", ""};
```

So, I have found another question. i have try it.

```
getAct.AddRange(a.MatchedALLlist[j].AllNewActionList);
```

And result is

```
listAll = { "B","S","","","","","","","","B","S","","","","","","","","B","S","")
```

but I  want to merge to one list like.

```
listAll = { "B","S","B","S","B","S","")
```

What should I do?

Comment: What's the rule of selection? **1)** What if each list contains a string in the same index, for example all lists contain "B" or "S" in the first index? **2**) What if the length of lists are not the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are sure that all lists have the same length and only one of the lists have non-empty element at each index, so you can get the expected result simply this way:

```
var result = list1.Select((x, i) => x + list2[i] + list3[i]).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

With extension method

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Merge<T(
    this IEnumerable<string> first,
    IEnumerable<string> second,
    IEnumerable<string> third)
{        
    using (var eFirst = first.GetEnumerator())
    using (var eSecond = second.GetEnumerator())
    using (var eThird = third.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (eFirst.MoveNext() && eSecond.MoveNext() && eThird.MoveNext())
        {
            var values = new[] { eFirst.Current, eSecond.Current, eThird.Current };
            yield return values.Where(value => string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) == false)
                               .DefaultIfEmpty("")
                               .First();
        }
    }
}
```

By using `while` we ensure that merge will be done amount of time equal to amount of items in smallest collection.

Then use it

```
var merged = list1.Merge(list2, list3);
```

Another approach (actually the same) where you can use already existed LINQ extension functions:
Use `FirstNonEmpty` method (from @dasblinkenlight's answer) and `Zip` method

```
var merge = 
    list1.Zip(list2, (value1, value2) => FirstNonEmpty(value1, value2))
         .Zip(list3, (value, value3) => FirstNonEmpty(value, value3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a simple answer is the best one.
Why not use the good old classic `for` loop:

```
var list1 = new List<string> { "B", "S", "", "", "", "", "" };
var list2 = new List<string> { "", "", "B", "S", "", "", "" };
var list3 = new List<string> { "", "", "", "", "B", "S", "" };
var list4 = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(list1[i]))
        list4.Add(list1[i]);
    else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(list2[i]))
        list4.Add(list2[i]);
    else
        list4.Add(list3[i]);
}
```

It should do what you want, as long as the lengths of all 3 lists are the same.